# NoSuchELementException even after element is being clicked but Test case fails throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: eclipse, automation, automated-tests, appium-android, nosuchelementexception

```
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.FrameLayout[@resourceid='com.infinite.netsfere:id/nav_meetings' and @index='4']")
public WebElement meetingIcon;
```

`

```
appium - 1.16.0


java client     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
         <version>7.0.0</version>
```

`

Element mentioned is clicked fine but still nosuchelementexception is thrown and the test case fails.
Tried updating the javaclient but received classDefound error.

Please help me on how this issue can be fixed.